# Figure captions with multiple plots in one chunk

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I label my figures like this.

```
---
title: "xxx"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: true
---
```

And then in each chunk

````
```{r, fig.cap="some caption"}
qplot(1:5)
```
````

This works quite nicely. However in chunks where I plot multiple figures within a loop I can't specify a caption. This produces no caption at all:

````
```{r, fig.cap="another caption"}
qplot(1:5)
qplot(6:10)
```
````

How can I specify a figure that counts from the same number as the first chunk for each plot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a fig.cap argument of length 2 (or the size of your loop):

````
```{r, fig.cap=c("another caption", "and yet an other")}
qplot(1:5)
qplot(6:10)
```
````

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly in a sample. Even better I can combine them in a previous chunk with a loop feeding my names list.

Comment: actually, you can even set it in the same chunk if you use `eval.after='fig.cap'` http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#package_options

Comment: Thanks Stackoverflow for automatically posting when hitting enter and then not letting me edit my comment. The important part of the above comment ist missing: This works perfectly in a sample. Even better I can combine them in a previous chunk with a loop feeding my names list. Unfortunately this does only work in a sample and not in my actual document with 26 names in the loop

Comment: Found the error. In the chunk I had message=FALSE cause the loop produces ## `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' for each item in the loop. The message=false also seem to suppress the figure caption. So is there another way that I can get rid of the message?

Comment: I think you need to ask another question with a MCVE

Comment: Not sure if still relevant to you but this is (kind of) resolved in a question I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998396/unset-existing-scale-fill-discrete-in-ggplot2-or-suppress-message-for-new-scale

Answer (score 2):

Found an easy way to dynamically produce plots and add them to the pdf with individual captions, using knitr::fig_chunk as described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/fig-chunk.html). This is also a workaround for OPs comment that `message=false` (or `echo=False` or `results='asis'` for that matter) supresses the `fig.cap` argument.

````
```{r my-plots, dev='png', fig.show='hide', echo=FALSE}
# generate plots first
qplot(1:5)
qplot(6:10)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
# then put them in the document with the captions
cat(paste0("![some caption](", fig_chunk(label = "my-plots", ext = "png", number = 1), ")\n\n"))
cat(paste0("![another caption](", fig_chunk(label = "my-plots", ext = "png", number = 2), ")\n\n"))
```
````

Hopefully this helps someone who stumbles upon this question in the future.